# Translate image top to bottom

Tags: java, android

Top to bottom animation on image:

I am using the following code to animate the image, while it is working for right to left animation I want to do the same top to bottom, how to improve this?

```
ai=new AccelerateInterpolator();
        TranslateAnimation ifr=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.04f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f);
        ifr.setDuration(400);
        ifr.setInterpolator(ai);

        set = new AnimationSet(false); 
        set.addAnimation(ifr);

        AlphaAnimation alphain=new AlphaAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
        alphain.setDuration(2500);
        set.addAnimation(alphain);
```

While I tried:

```
ai=new AccelerateInterpolator();
        TranslateAnimation ifr=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.02f);
        ifr.setDuration(400);
        ifr.setInterpolator(ai);

        set = new AnimationSet(false); 
        set.addAnimation(ifr);

        AlphaAnimation alphain=new AlphaAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
        alphain.setDuration(2500);
        set.addAnimation(alphain);
```

but the image flickers at the end, that is image comes down gradually but then moves back to original position with a jump

WHat I want is that image comes from a 2px above from original position then settles down.

Comment: Found the answer: `set.setFillAfter(true);`